# undo/inverse a function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry

I have a smallish math function, and I don't have access to the change the function itself, only undo it via reverse functions. I have the output var5 at the end, and I know the function to get to it. I don't however know how get to var6, if possible. I'm using java, but that probably doesn't matter since there is not likely to be a magic API to fix this.

Long story short-> I have var5 at the end, I need var6 at declaration. I haven't the slightest clue how to get there.

var5 is a float predefined, had other stuff done to it, not important.  var6 is a storage variable to retain var5's value while the first function changes it

```
float var6 = var5;
float var7 = 1.0F - (float)((Math.cos((double)var5 * Math.PI) + 1.0D) / 2.0D);
float var8 = var6 + (var7 - var6) / 3.0F;
```

I have var8, I need var6.

Comment: do you mean you need to know what var6 is before you've computed var5?  I'm not sure what you mean by you need var6 at declaration.

Comment: It would be much clearer if the code didn't re-use (re-define) variables. Unless that's important for some reason other saving memory.

Comment: that's just there so i can explain what i have and what i need, they're irrelevant to the actual problem, arrange it however you want my issue is the math, not programming

Comment: I'm beginning to think it's impossible  
`var5 = (float) (Math.acos((double)(((var6 - var8)  * 2/3 )  - (2 * var6) + 1)) / Math.PI);`  
is as far as I got

Comment: I just ran a simulation that dumped hundreds of values and did a regression, it's not the most accurate but good enough because it's almost linear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First let's change the notation a bit. Let
$$u = var6  \quad ; \quad  v = var7  \quad ; \quad  w = var8$$
We can ignore $var5$ because it's just equal to $var6$, anyway.

Then, after removing all the Java complications, your code says:
$$
v = 1 - \tfrac12\left(\cos\pi u + 1\right) = \tfrac12\left(1 - \cos\pi u \right) \\
w = u + \tfrac13(v-u) = \tfrac13 v + \tfrac23 u
$$
Combining these, we get
$$
w = \tfrac16\left(1 - \cos\pi u \right) + \tfrac23 u
$$

So, if I understand your question correctly, you have a given value of $w$ ($var8$), and you want to find the corresponding value of $u$ ($var6$) that satisfies this last equation.

There is no closed form solution, so you'll need to use numerical methods.

Except over very small ranges of $u$, this doesn't look even close to linear, to me, so I suggest you re-examine your regression calculations.

Comment: @Thomas: If you do end up using a numerical algorithm to solve for $u$ (e.g. Newton's method) then a good initial guess might be $u = \frac{3}{2} w - \frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: var8 is always very small, because var6 is between 0-24000